# My PC won't detect any wifi

Tags: wireless-networking

So one day I went to turn on my computer and saw It wasn't connected to my wifi, so I went to settings and it turns out my computer wasn't even detecting my wifi, but for some reason all my other electronics could find and use the wifi. So I Tried connecting my cellphone's hotspot to it and the computer did not detect the wifi 
 I am running windows 8.1 and I have a Hp pavilion 20

Comment: Maybe you just have to power on your Wifi Adapter using a button or a keyboard key ?

Comment: Yep, it's likely that your WiFi adapter has gotten turned off.  There may be a physical switch, a keyboard combo, or a setting of some sort.

Comment: If all else fails, and you cannot find a way to enable it, try removing the device in device manager, and reinstalling it.

Comment: I have already checked and it is turned on

Comment: I have also tried reinstalling it

Comment: This is what the error says "Windows cannot verify the digital signature for the drivers required for this device.A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source. (Code 52)" And the adapter name is Qualcomm Atheros AR9485

Comment: @Neon_Toaster You should edit that info into your question.... way to easy to miss it in comments.